# Suppose $V$ is a vector space such that the only subspaces of $V$ are $\{0\}$ and $V$. Determine the dimension of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $V$ is a vector space such that the only subspaces of $V$ are $\{0\}$ and $V$. Determine the dimension of $V$.

I have no idea how to prove that. I know that $\{0\}$ and $V$ are always subspaces of $V$. That is we have to find subspace having no proper subspaces and find its dimension. How to get this. Please help.

Comment: are you familiar with the concept of "span of a vector"?

Comment: @user347489 yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $v\in V$ be a non-zero vector. Then $\Bbb R\cdot v = \{r\cdot v: r\in\Bbb R\}$ is a subspace. Since it is clearly not the zero subspace, it is all of $V$ by assumption. So by definition $V$ has dimension $1$.

Comment: you have mentioned $\Bbb R\cdot v = \{r\cdot v: r\in\Bbb R\}$ is a subspace of $V$. what type of product  $r⋅v$ is? Please elaborate with a example.

Comment: @rama_ran it is scalar multiplication, which is in the axioms for a vector space.

Comment: Ok then it is a subspace of V. But how you conclude that dim V as 1

Comment: @rama_ran one vector forms a basis, by definition the size of a basis is the dimension.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $x\in V$. The subspace spanned by $x$ is

$$\langle x\rangle=\{y\in V,\, \exists \lambda\in \Bbb{K}\,y=\lambda x\}$$

Now by assumption $\langle x\rangle=\{0\}\text{ or }V$. So either $x=0$ or it spans the whole space and this means the dimension is $0$ (trivial case) or $1$.

Answer (score 1):

The dimension is equal to 1.

Recall that the dimension of a vector space $V$ is given by the number of basis vectors it has. Since $V$ is not the null-space we know the dimension is at least 1. Every finite dimensional vector space $V$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$. We also can always find a subspace of dimension $n-1$ by removing one basis vector. Since the only subspace (the zero space) has dimension 0, $V$ must have dimension $1$, because if it didn't, then we could find a $n-1$ dimensional subspace.

Comment: Are you sure that the dimension zero space, $\left\{\vec{0}\right\}$ is excluded? I suppose this is like asking if the integer 1 is prime, but still.

Comment: the dimensions are equal, and so they are isomorphic. To show this, we would need to construct some linear map that is isomorphic that sends basis vectors to basis vectors. Since this is finite dimensional, it is isomorphic to some $\mathbb{R}^n$, but here $n=0$ which is just the zero vector, since if there was a non-zero vector, any scalar $c$ would make the space span $\mathbb{R}$, which has dimension 1, and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: @SeanLake 1 isn't a prime, this is not like that.

Comment: @AdamHughes Naive definition of prime: integer evenly divisible by only 1 and itself.
Definition of this set: only vector subspaces are $\left\{\vec{0}\right\}$ and itself.

Comment: @SeanLake 1 is not considered a prime, there is no "naive" definition of a prime. A prime is an integer greater than 1, evenly divisible by 1 and itself. If 1 were a prime, this would essentially destroy hundreds, if not thousands of theorems in number theory, and results in other fields which use number theoretic tools. At any rate, the question has been answered.