# $V$ a $K$-vector space has only two subspaces: $\{0_V\}$ and itself, $V$. Prove that the dimension of $V$ is $\dim V=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, vector-spaces

$V$ a $K$-vector space has only two subspaces: $\{0_V\}$ and itself, $V$. Prove that the dimension of $V$ is $\dim V=1$

---

We know that:

If $W\leq V$, then $\dim W\leq\dim V$, and if $\dim W=\dim V$, we know that $W=V$

---

My try:

First case: $W=\{0_V\}$, we know $W\leq V$ and $\dim W=0$

The basis for the previous subspace: $\beta_w=\emptyset$

We can take a vector $v$ from $V$ ($v\in V$) then $W'=\langle v\rangle$ will also be a subspace with basis $\beta_{w'}=\{v\}$, of dimension 1 ($\dim W'=1$)

We found 2 subspaces of $V$, our hypothesis is that $V$ has just 2 subspaces, then $W'=V$ and therefore $\dim V=1$.

---

[Found this same exercise here but I don't understand the answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2042878/suppose-v-is-a-vector-space-such-that-the-only-subspaces-of-v-are-0-an)

Comment: Your argument seems to be about the same then the one linked too. It is not clear what you do not understand about it. Anyway,  it's basically correct. You should not say though that there is no basis for W. It does have a basis, which is empty. The empty set is still a set.

Comment: Thanks I'll keep that in mind